# Why does recursion overwrite values in a list that is passed along?

Tags: python, recursion, tree, permutation, combinatorics

This recusion is adapted from http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/ and does indeed print out all possible unique combination of `arr` with length `r`.

What I want from it is to save all possible combination in a list to further use this algorithm in another program. Why is the values overritten in `combArray` in the recustion and how do I solve this?

```
def combRecursive(arr, data, start, end, index, r, combArray):
    if index == r:
        combArray.append(data)
        return combArray

    i = start
    while True:
        if i > end or end - i + 1 < r - index:
            break
        data[index] = arr[i]
        combArray = combRecursive(arr, data, i + 1, end, index + 1, r, combArray)
        i += 1
    return combArray

def main():
    arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    r = 3
    n = len(arr)
    data = [9999999, 9999999, 9999999]
    combArray = []

    combArray = combRecursive(arr, data, 0, n-1, 0, r, combArray)
    print("All possible unique combination is: ")
    for element in combArray:
        print(element)
```

Result as of now:

```
[3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
```

What I want:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 5]
[1, 3, 4]
[1, 3, 5]
[1, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 5]
[2, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: @Prune: I don't see any default arguments here.

Comment: What you want is `[list(x) for x in itertools.combinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3)]` instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @user2357112: thanks ... I apparently clicked through the list too quickly.  I can't edit the reference, but this issue has been handled on SO many times before.

Comment: The answer to your question is that you are *appending the exact same list every time*. `combArray.append(data)`

Comment: @Prune - You're not wrong that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575196/in-python-why-can-a-function-modify-some-arguments-as-perceived-by-the-caller) has [come](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322068/python-passing-list-as-argument) up many [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379991/python-unintentionally-modifying-parameters-passed-into-a-function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize `data`, and from then on make changes to it & add it to `combArray`, which means you are always adding *the same array* to `combArray`, so all of its elements are the same.  If you want the elements to be distinct arrays, you need to make a new array for each you want to add to `combArrays` (by, for example, making a copy of `data`).

Comment: I.E a solution would be to change `combArray.append(data)` to `combArray.append(data[:])`. Great, thanks!